# How to run a file with imported ES6 modules in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a react app set up with webpack, and would like to also have a script that runs in node to write stuff into output file, such as:

**script.mjs**

```
import fs from 'fs';
import {SomeClass} from './index.js';

const outputFile= fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.png');

// Writes into output file
```

and have the following script command in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "runFile": "node --experimental-modules test/script.mjs",
  ...
}
```

Whenever I run `npm run runFile` it complains with:

```
import {SomeClass} from './index.js';
        ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './index.js' does not provide an export named 'SomeClass'
```

even though it exists in that file:

**./index.js**

`export SomeClass from './SomeClass';`

I even used `node -r esm test/script.js` to run in node, but it keeps complaining about ES6 `exports` all the time. Could anybody point me to how to run a js file that has ES6 stuff with `node` command?

**NODE v10**

Comment: what's your node version? This oughtn't be a problem with ^v13

Comment: it's node version 10

Answer (score 0):

There is a small inconsistency in your export/import statements.

Oh, and you are exporting from an entirely different file. Is there are reason you need to do so?

You may export an containing your class

```
export { someClass
```

Then you can import it with the present import statement.

More direct would be to export from your `./someClass` file with a default export

```
export default someClass
```

then import it without destructuring the object:

```
import some class from './someClass';
```

The latter would fit well with the file name and is a style expected by most.

Note that when you run old node versions you need some extra CLI flags to run modules. With present node (^13) it is enough to set *type: module*. See Hao Wu's answer.